# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FormulairesController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I'm a beginner in Ruby, I want to develop a Google Form like application so I generated 3 models 'Formulaire' 'Questions' and 'Choix'. I have an Active record error when i want to create choices for my questions. I understood the error but i don't know how to fix it.

My formulaires_controller :

```
def new
  @formulaire = current_user.formulaires.new
 end

def create
  @formulaire = current_user.formulaires.new(formulaire_params) 
  if @formulaire.save    
    redirect_to @formulaire, notice: "Votre formulaire a bien été crée"   
  else     
    render :new
  end
end

def edit
  set_formulaire
  @formulaire.questions.new  
end

 def set_formulaire
  @formulaire = Formulaire.find(params[:id])
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])

 end

def update
  set_formulaire
  if @formulaire.update(formulaire_params)
  redirect_to @formulaire, notice: "Modification enregistrée"
else
  render :edit
 end
 end
```

My Formulaire model :

```
 class Formulaire < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true


 validates :name, presence: true
 validates :description, presence: true


end
```

Comment: Your `set_formulaire` method is trying to find *both* a formulaire and a question using the same id (`params[:id]`) - that's probably not what you intended.

Comment: what have written in `set_formulaire` ?

Comment: @Gabbar it's in the question - after the `edit` method

Comment: @mikej Yes but how can i find a formulaire and a question with different id's ? My Formulaire and Question models have a has_many relation and Question / Choices too.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. For example if you want to display a form and all of its questions in the `show` then you wouldn't want to fetch a *single* question by id. Instead you'd use `@formulaire.questions` in a loop. To edit a single question you might want to look into _nested routes_ and then you'd have a separate `formulaire_id` and `id` (for the question).

Comment: I want to edit several choices for a question when i'm editing it. If I add      @question = @formulaire.questions  in my set_formulaire method and     @question.choixes.new in my edit i have an other NoMethodError in FormulairesController#edit (undefined method `choixes' for #<Question::...)